# how to conver a string like this "EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z" to a js Date object (with dojo)

Tags: javascript, string, date, design-patterns, dojo

I am trying to convert the java date object to a js date object, the string is like:

> EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z

and I am using Dojo.

The following will return an invalid value in FF and IE, but a valid Date object in Chrome:

```
var s = "Fri 21 Sep 2012 11:29:34:258 UTC", 
d = new Date(s), dojo.date.locale.format(d);
while new Date("Fri 21 Sep 2012 11:29:34:258 UTC")
```

Then I tried to use `dojo.date.locale.parse`, but it still doesn't work:

```
dojo.date.locale.parse("Fri 21 Sep 2012 11:29:34:258 UTC", 
{datePattern:"EEE dd MMM yyyy", timePattern:"HH:mm:ss:SSS Z"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example using `dojo/date/locale` actually appears to work in Dojo 1.8, and the date is correctly parsed: http://jsfiddle.net/dJ6ms/